# SAS: Expressions in IF statement

Tags: if-statement, expression, sas

does Sas provide mechanism of `chain`-expressions?

does Sas provide mechanism of `In`-clause?

Simple examples:

```
  a = '09MAY2010'd;
  b = '17MAY2010'd;

if (a<=c<=b) then do; /*code*/ end;
if (c in (a:b)) then do; /*code*/ end;
```

maybe any good techniques of if/where statements?
your suggestions and advises, please.
Thanks!

Comment: thanks! i've cleared my misknowledge

Comment: if you figured it out, you should post and answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example, changed a bit:

```
data _null_;
    a = '09MAY2010'd;
    b = '17MAY2010'd;
    c = '17MAY2010'd;

    if (a<=c<=b) then do;
        putlog "a<=c<=b";
    end;

    select (c); 
        when (a, b) putlog "in a, b";
        when ('17MAY2010'd) putlog "'17MAY2010'd";/* not used, only first match is executed */
        otherwise;
    end;

run;
```

IN operator used with IF or in WHERE clause requires constants in the list.

Comment: good one, but what about second one? (`c in (a:b)`) am i right, that i can't use `IF-statement` with range, only IF each border of range is constant?

Comment: not sure what you mean: if (a<=c<=b) is effectively reference to range defined by variables, not constants.

Comment: no-no, i mean `(c in (a:b))` as a range. chain-comparisons are worked.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `IN` operator, which only accepts constant values inside the paranthesis, there is also an (undocumented) `IN` function, which can be used with variables, so instead of `if c in(a,b)` you can use `if in(c,a,b)` which will work also when a and b are variables.

Another possibility is to use `WHICHN` or `WHICHC` functions, which has the same syntax, and which return `0` (`FALSE`) when a match is not found, and otherwise the number of the (first) match.